# pass formik.values to another js file

Tags: reactjs, formik, stepper

I learn react and I am trying to create a stepper to manage my form correct,I'm looking for the best fit way to pass input value from one step to another
**The full code is bellow**

here the input value from step 1 :

```
   <MDBInput
   label="exerciseManager"
   name="exerciseManager"
   type="text"
   value={formik.values.exerciseManager}
   onChange={formik.handleChange}
   outline
   size="lg"
   />
```

**I want to pass formik.values.exerciseManager to step 2 so i can use it there**

step 1 and step 2 in different js file

how should I do that correct?

this is step 1 : [image: step1]

I want it will show here : [image: step2]

**full step 1 code**

```
//now check that the value get correct to the database
const Certifications = (props) => {
//state             //Setstate
const [fieldApproveOptions, setFieldApproveOptions] = useState([])

//useEffect Hooks 
useEffect(() => {

    axios.get('/api/certifications/fieldApproveOptions?userId=1234567&rank=Colonel&force=Moran')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setFieldApproveOptions(response.data.fieldApproveOptions)
        }
        ).catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [])

const formik = useFormik({

    initialValues: {
        exerciseName: '',
        //exerciseBy: '',  autofill current user from session
        exerciseOOB: '',
        exercisePOD: '',
        exerciseType: '', // options should be pull from db
        exerciseLive: '',
        fieldApprove: '', // options should be pull from db
        fileApprove: '', // options should be pull from db
        artilleryApprove: '', // options should be pull from db
        exerciseManager: '',
        trainerOfficerApprove: '', // options should be pull from db
        cerRes: '',
        fieldApproveOptions: []

    },

    onSubmit: values => {
        axios.post('/api/certifications', values)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
})

return (
    <Card>
        <CardContent>
            <div className="Pedding">
                <MDBContainer fluid  >

                    <MDBRow center  >
                        <MDBCol md="4"  >
                            <div className="MDBColor">
                                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
                                    <p className="h1 text-center" style={{ paddingTop: "10px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Certifications</p>
                                    <div className="Certifications">

                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="Exercise name"
                                            name="exerciseName"
                                            type="text"
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            value={formik.values.exerciseName}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"
                                        />


                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="Exercise type"
                                            name="exerciseType"
                                            list="types"
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            value={formik.values.exerciseType}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"

                                        />

                                        <datalist id="types" >
                                            <option data-value="1" value="Open Terrain">Open Terrain</option>
                                            <option value="Urban warfare" >Urban warfare</option>
                                            <option value="Armoured fighting vehicle" >Armoured fighting vehicle</option>
                                            <option value="unplanned" >unplanned</option>
                                            <option value="live military exercise" >live military exercise</option>
                                        </datalist>






                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="Order of battle"
                                            name="exerciseOOB"
                                            type="number"
                                            min="20"
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            value={formik.values.exerciseOOB}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"
                                        />



                                        {/*FieldApprove button */}
                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="fieldApprove"
                                            name="fieldApprove"
                                            list="fieldApproves"
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            value={formik.values.fieldApprove}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"
                                        />
                                        <datalist id="fieldApproves" defaultValue>

                                            {fieldApproveOptions.map((option, i) =>
                                                <option key={i++} value={option.id}>
                                                    {option.rank + " " + option.firstName + " " + option.lastName}
                                                </option>)}
                                        </datalist>




                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="fileApprove"
                                            name="fileApprove"
                                            type="text"
                                            value={formik.values.fileApprove}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"
                                        />
                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="artilleryApprove"
                                            name="artilleryApprove"
                                            type="text"
                                            value={formik.values.artilleryApprove}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"
                                        />
                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="exerciseManager"
                                            name="exerciseManager"
                                            type="text"
                                            value={formik.values.exerciseManager}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"
                                          

                                            
                                           

                                        />
                                        

                                        <MDBInput
                                            label="trainerOfficerApprove"
                                            name="trainerOfficerApprove"
                                            type="text"
                                            value={formik.values.trainerOfficerApprove}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            outline
                                            size="lg"

                                        />

                                        <div style={{ fontSize: "large", fontWeight: "bold" }} className="custom-control custom-checkbox">

                                            <input type="checkbox"
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                value={formik.values.exerciseLive}
                                                className="custom-control-input"
                                                name="exerciseLive"
                                                id="live"
                                                value="on"

                                            />
                                            <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="live"> live exercise</label>
                                        </div>





                                        {/*pod section*/}
                                        <span style={{ fontSize: "large", fontWeight: "bold", float: "left" }} >part of the day:</span>
                                        <div className="forms" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.exercisePOD}  >
                                            {/*night button*/}
                                            <label htmlFor="rdo1">
                                                <input type="radio" id="rdo1" name="exercisePOD" value="night" />
                                                <span className="rdo"></span>
                                                <span>night</span>
                                            </label>
                                            {/*day button*/}
                                            <label htmlFor="rdo2">
                                                <input type="radio" id="rdo2" name="exercisePOD" value="day" />
                                                <span className="rdo"></span>
                                                <span>day</span>
                                            </label>

                                        </div>






                                        <div className="text-center">
                                            <MDBBtn type="submit" color="yellow">Send</MDBBtn>
                                        </div>
                                    </div >
                                </form >
                            </div>
                        </MDBCol>
                    </MDBRow>

                </MDBContainer >

            </div>
        </CardContent>
    </Card>
);



}

export default Certifications;
```

here Soform.js full code

```
        const SoForm = () => {



 return (

   <p >
{formik.values.exerciseManager}
  </p>
 )
     }
   export default SoForm;
```

**Here formikStepper code**

```
export default function Home() {
return (
<Card>
  <CardContent>
    <FormikStepper
      initialValues={{
   
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await sleep(3000);
        console.log('values', values);
      }}
    >
      <FormikStep label="Certifications">
        <Box paddingBottom={2}>
        <Certifications   ></Certifications>
        </Box>
      </FormikStep>
      <FormikStep 
        label="loginPageF"

      >
        <Box paddingBottom={2}>
        <SoForm ></SoForm>
```

Comment: you want to pass it to child component, parent, or sibling.. or completely un-related  components ? if child -> use props, if parent -> use callback, if sibling -> mix both.. completely un-related ? -> use react-redux

Comment: you can use the [useFormik hook](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) to get values. since I don't know the details of your form, I am not sure if that would work. I believe session storage is often used in that case, since with redux a refresh would delete all the data

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Hi step 1 and step 2 in different js file

Comment: @tachko Hi I add two picture so it will be more understandable
in the picture i fill the filed I want to show at step 2

Comment: they are in different js file, as they should be.. but what are their relation in between ?? from the illustrations you have provided I can make an wild guess that, there is some `Parent` component, where `Certification`, `Login` lies... if you provide minimal code, I can implement it there..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad hi I did it can you help me now?...

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to read and understands your code. Try to provide minimal reproducible statements. I can understand you problem, but can't work with your code. So I have created my won example. Here, codesandbox.io : https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-shtern-362ki?file=/src/App.js

Let me explain it for you.

```
index.js -> is entry point, that calls only one component App, as we have no route
App.js -> is the parent component, which has two child, Certification and Panel
Certification.js -> takes input
Panel -> renders data from certification
```

If I'm not wrong, that's what you want. Render data in a component to another component, which are siblings to one another.

**App.js :**

```
import React from "react";
import Certifications from "./Certifications";
import Panel from "./Panel";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value1: "",
    value2: ""
  };

  fromCert = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value1}
        {this.state.value2}
        <Certifications fromCert={this.fromCert} />
        <Panel value1={this.state.value1} value2={this.state.value2} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Panel.js**:

```
import React from "react";

class Panel extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Here we will render data from App, below
        <div>{this.props.value1}</div>
        <div>{this.props.value2}</div>
        Panel ends
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Panel;
```

**Certification.js**:

```
import React from "react";

class Certifications extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input1: "",
    input2: ""
  };
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    this.props.fromCert(e.target.name, e.target.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name="value1" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input name="value2" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <div>
          Inside certificate
          <div>{this.state.input1}</div>
          <div>{this.state.input2}</div>
          Certificate ends
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Certifications;
```

First of all, Certifications have two states - *value1, value2*. So I have given two input's name *value1, value2*. So that I can set value dynamically. [Why? - just imagine I have 10 or 20 states. And that you have in your code.](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/understanding-this-setstate-name-value-a5ef7b4ea2b4)

And onChange of value, I'm triggering a callback to App with `fromCert`. Try passing 1000+ parameter, it will. :wink:

When I'm triggering that callback from certification, it's getting called in `App.js`'s fromCert. Why is that? Cause I have passed that function or method as parameter - `<Certifications fromCert={this.fromCert} />`. So that's the reason why this function or method acts as callback. When I get those values, I just set them to `App.js`'s state. Then pass them as `props` to Panel.

So whatever changes gets applied to **Certification** that comes to **App**, which then gets passed to **Panel**.

```
Certification -> App : Child to Parent communication
App -> Panel : Parent to Child communication
Certification -> Panel : Child to Child communication / Sibling communication
```

Try to imagine the hierarchy.

Thanks a lot. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi first I want to Tank you !! on that solution. but this is not solve my case,
yes you understand correct the hierarchy but the solve is for regular rcf and I use at rff and not regular rff I use formik hooks

Comment: @checkeverytime facebook recommends to use rff, but I don't know why I love rcf... but the logic and underlying architectures are the same, right ?? if this helps you upvote.. cause formik hooks just return state of that component/functional-component.. so I think the use case is covered here.. thanks..

Comment: I make simple example here to explain my problem better 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925561/formik-stepper-propshooks-between-steps