# Formik stepper props+hooks between steps

Tags: reactjs, formik, stepper

I am trying to pass data in a component to another component, which are siblings to one another.But they are in a `Formik Stepper` with `Formik Hook(rff)`.

```
index.js -> is entry point, that calls only one component App, as we have no route
App.js -> this the parent component, which has two child, Step1 and Step2
Step1.js -> takes input
Step2.js -> renders data from Step1
```

I made a simple example code here the link

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-germain-formikstepper-xntko?file=/src/

- **Note that**
  I don't want to put all  formik initialValues in the main formik stepper component
  because In my **real project** I have a lot of values at step 1 and step 2 and  I have  there more steps in the stepper with more values,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer -

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";
export default function Step2() {

const{values} =  useFormikContext()
return <p>{values.firstName} </p>;
}
```

**full solution**
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-germain-formiksteppersol-xntko?file=/src/App.tsx